# Accurate value from the JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

Trying to match the value with the JSON value by wrirting a for loop, but everytime once the loop is completes it is returning 2345 value only. Where am I going wrong can anyone help me out.
And I have a term which dynamically generates a string value.

```
var mKey = doc.search.searchBy.split(",")[0].split("=")[1].replace(/\s+/, "").toLowerCase();
```

JSON:

```
{
    "records" : {
        "cat1" : [
            {
                "id" : 1234,
                "label":"a"
            },
            {
                "id" : 2345,
                "label":"b"

            }
        ],
        "cat2" : {

            "id" : 12345,
            "label" : "c"
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
var array = doc.records.cat1;
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    var oID = array[i].id.toString();
}
if (oID === "2345" && mKey=="Apple") {
    console.log("Apple");
    break;
}
else if (oID === "1234" && mKey=="Banana") {
    console.log("Banana")
}
else {
    console.log('other fruits');
}
```

Comment: it is so because cat1's first entity has no such term as id, also include you if statements in for loop.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place your `if` statement within the `for` loop so that it relates to the current iteration:

```
var array = doc.records.cat1;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var oID = array[i].id.toString();

    if (oID === "2345") {
        console.log("success");
    }
    else if (oID === "1234") {
        console.log("error")
    }
    else {
        console.log('other');
    } 
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/braKP/)

Note that a `break` statement is irrelevant inside an `if` block.

Answer (score 3):

You have closed your loop in wrong place, I guess

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    var oID = array[i].id.toString();

    if (oID === "2345") {
        console.log("success");
        break;
    }
    else if (oID === "1234") {
        console.log("error")
    }
    else {
        console.log('other');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All if structure comes under for loop

```
var array = doc.records.cat1;
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    var oID = array[i].id.toString();

if (oID === "2345" && mKey=="Apple") {
    console.log("Apple");
    break;
}
else if (oID === "1234" && mKey=="Banana") {
    console.log("Banana")
}
else {
    console.log('other fruits');
} 

}
```

Comment: for the first time it is returning if condition and else condition also.